# Floating point comparison in general unit tests

Tags: c++, algorithm, unit-testing, floating-point, numeric

I know this question has been discussed a lot. I searched the web and come up with an algorithm myself. I'm wondering whether it can serve as a default implementation that works fine in general unit tests (not some serious/professional numeric tests).

```
bool equal_to(double x, double y) {
  using limits = std::numeric_limits<double>;
  auto mag_x = std::abs(x);
  auto mag_y = std::abs(y);
  if (mag_x < mag_y) {
    std::swap(x, y);
    std::swap(mag_x, mag_y);
  }
  auto eps = limits::epsilon() * mag_x;
  auto lb = x - eps;
  auto ub = x + eps;
  return lb < y && y < ub;
}
```

Just found a flaw. The last statement should be

```
return (x == y) || (lb < y && y < ub);
```

in case `equal_to(0, 0);`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DanielDaranas I'm wondering whether there is any significant flaws in this algorithm that make it unsuitable to be used in general unit tests to compare floating point values.

Comment: What's the point of the swaps? `eps` just needs `std::max(mag_x, mag_y)` and if x within eps of y then y is also within eps of x. Equivalently, `abs(x-y)<eps`.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, you're right :-)

Comment: @MSalters I guess I just don't want to do the subtraction. So I used the swap.

Comment: Easier fix for the flaw would be `lb<=y && y <=ub`.

Comment: @MSalters But that would in incorrect if not for the `0.0, 0.0` case.

Comment: @Lingxi: You probably have an overly optimistic view of numerical precision. FP math is not magic, rounding errors can compound.

Comment: Don't call this `equal_to`. It's `nearly_equal`. That will save a great deal of confusion.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's actually a template overload. It's only selected for floating point comparisons. Others will use `==` directly. So, the *nearly equal* semantics is really a hidden implementation detail.

Comment: No, it's not a hidden detail. It will return `true` for two **different** values. That is **not** equality. In particular, it is not transitive. So `a` nearly-equals `b` and `b` nearly-equals `c` does not imply that `a` nearly-equals `c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't sufficient. Your `eps` is too low and should probably be multiplied with the number of steps used to produce `x` and `y` (although these errors *often* cancel, this isn't guaranteed).

Furthermore, your rounding effects may be amplified by catastrophic cancellation. If `x` is about 0.1 because it was calculated as `10.0 - 9.9` then you should have used `limits::epsilon * (10+9.9)`. You're too optimistic by about a factor of 100.

Comment: Well, I guess there is no general solution that works in all cases. Otherwise, the standard library should have provided such a thing in `<numeric>` or something.